# What API should be used for real-time audio in OSX?

Tags: macos, core-audio, audioqueueservices

I am looking to build an application that requires real-time control (or as good as possible) control of audio output in OSX.

I need the ability to send samples of audio to the sound-card with as much control as possible, no delays as when the audio frames are sent will be closely tied to a timer event run via the clock.

Is the Audio Queue what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Audio Units can be configured for the lowest latency (using short buffers of raw PCM sample) in OS X and iOS.  The Audio Queue API is built on top of Audio Units, and may have buffering overhead, thus increasing latency.